# Cannot launch AVD in emulator in android studio 2.2

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

### dev env:

win10 + android studio 2.2

### Error below:

Cannot launch AVD in emulator.

Output:

Hax is enabled

Hax ram_size 0x60000000

HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.

Assertion failed!

Program: D:\Apps\DevEnv\android-sdk\tools\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-i386.exe

File: /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/emu-2.2-release/external/qemu-android/util/error.c, Line 70

Expression: *errp == NULL

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.

Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in SDK Tools.

Look here for the bug report: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223100&q=null&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened

In the post there is a link to a local build with a fix, which can be used until the new offical version is ready: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B73KGLi34py3elpuelE1OVVDZGc/view?usp=sharing

It worked fine for me.